# How to add city names in arcgis offline map?

Tags: c#, arcgis, layer, esri-maps

I am making an offline map application using arcgis .net sdk. Here I print the map with image tile. So, I have the images of the map in PNG format. I can use the map offline by displaying it as a map with the help of arcgis WebTiledLayer. However, since everything is visual here, cities, streets, street names, etc. not shown. How can I add these to the map? How can I show it?

This is my code to print the map on the screen:

```
const string path= "C:\\\\map\\\\{level}\\\\{col}\\\\{row}.png";    
WebTiledLayer webLayer = new(path);    
Basemap layerBaseMap = new();    
layerBaseMap.BaseLayers.Add(webLayer);    
map = new Map(layerBaseMap);    
_mapView.Map = map;
```

I wonder if I can do it using featurelayer? How can I do it?

Comment: how do you intend to read features from a png-file? Of course you can use a featurelayer, however you need a service that provides *features*, not *images*.

Comment: " How can I add these to the map?" I don't understand. What exactly do you want to add? The PNG? From what I understand you already *do* show it in your app. Or do you have some layers (like streets) that you want to add on top of your image?

Comment: Yes, I can already show the map on the screen. However, I also want to show city names. I realized that this would be added in another layer. But I don't know how to do it. Does Arcgis have such support? Or should I follow a different path?

Comment: you can add a featurelayer onto your map. However I assume texts to be stored within an `AnnotationLayer`, not a `FeatureLayer`. Anyway you just add that layer to the `map`, not to the `BaseMap`, as you can only add image-layers to basemaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all kinds of different layers to your `Map` using the `OperationalLayers`-property. From your question it seems you have some feature-layers (e.g. streets and cities) as well as annotation-layers (streenames). You need to add these to your map:

```
const string path= "C:\\\\map\\\\{level}\\\\{col}\\\\{row}.png";    
WebTiledLayer webLayer = new(path);    
Basemap layerBaseMap = new();    
layerBaseMap.BaseLayers.Add(webLayer);  

map = new Map(layerBaseMap);

var citiesLayer = new FeatureLayer(new ServiceFeatureTable(myCitiesFeatureServiceUrl));
var streetNames = new AnnotationLayer(myStreetnamesServiceUrl);
map.OperationalLayers.Add(cities);
map.OperationalLayers.Add(streeNames);

_mapView.Map = map;
```

Be aware on the order of the `Add`-statements, as it will imply which layers are above and which ones are beyond. So whatever you add first, might be hidden by the last added layer, for instance.

Comment: So, how do I find the URL of city names? No matter how much I searched, I couldn't find it.

Comment: How should we know? You need to know the url of the services you want to show. No idea if this is ArcGIS Enterprise or ArcGIS Online.

Comment: hello, so, where is the download city names package? For offline map. Idont want to URL,because my map is offline.

Comment: @anonimusBird see https://developers.arcgis.com/net/offline-maps-scenes-and-data/work-with-offline-data/ for working with offline-data (which, by the way, you didn't mention in your question at all).